# python gui calculator, how should i force operands to work on number variables between them?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, calculator, operands

I got this GUI calculator working with two numbers and now I want to add a third number. I got it working with addition, then multiplication.. then adding a lot of numbers and subtracting/dividing after the adds or multiplying. Now if I try to get it to be a little bit more complicated I'm getting confused, because I may have set it up wrong.

The logic is something like this:
6 * 6 - 1 (calculators on windows don't do order of operations)
But in my script,

6 is first stored as evar.

Then the `multiply` function is called by the * button.

The `multiply` function appends evar to a list called FirstNumber.

The second 6 is now stored in evar.

The `divide` function is called by the / button.

The logic in `divide` is to set evar to FirstNumber.

Now the second 6 is set in firstNumber.

However, since firstNumber is a list, the sum of the two values are 12. However, I want it to be 36.
 If I now subtract 1 on the calculator,I want it to be 35, but logically it's going to be 11.

The list doesn't know what operands are pressed between numbers, can someone steer me toward a way to do this?

```
import sys
import os
from tkinter import *
from operator import mul


class Calculator():    
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()

        self.root.title("Calculator")

        self.frame1 = Frame(self.root)
        self.frame2 = Frame(self.root)
        self.frame3 = Frame(self.root)
        self.frame4 = Frame(self.root)
        self.frame5 = Frame(self.root)

        self.frame1.pack(side=TOP)
        self.frame2.pack(side=TOP)
        self.frame3.pack(side=TOP)
        self.frame4.pack(side=TOP)
        self.frame5.pack(side=TOP)

        self.evar = StringVar()

        self.evar.trace("w", self.callback)
        self.ent = Entry(self.frame1, textvariable = self.evar).pack(side=LEFT, padx = 10, pady= 10)

        self.button7 = Button(self.frame2, text="7", bg="white", fg="black", bd=20, command=lambda : self.append_button(7))
        self.button7.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.button8 = Button(self.frame2, text="8", bg="white", bd=20, fg="black", relief="raised", command=lambda : self.append_button(8))
        self.button8.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.button9 = Button(self.frame2, text = "9", bg="white", bd=20, fg="black", relief="raised", command=lambda : self.append_button(9))
        self.button9.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.Divbutton = Button(self.frame2, text = "/", bg="white", bd=20, fg="black", relief="raised", command= self.divide)
        self.Divbutton.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.button4 = Button(self.frame3, text="4", bg="white", bd=20, fg="black", relief="raised", command=lambda : self.append_button(4))
        self.button4.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.button5 = Button(self.frame3, text="5", bg="white", bd=20, fg="black", relief="raised", command=lambda : self.append_button(5))
        self.button5.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.button6 = Button(self.frame3, text = "6", bg="white", bd=20, fg="black", relief="raised", command=lambda : self.append_button(6))
        self.button6.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.MultiplyButton = Button(self.frame3, text = "*", bg="white", bd=20, fg="black", relief="raised", command = self.multiply).pack(side=LEFT)
        self.button1 = Button(self.frame4, text="1", bg="white", bd=20, fg="black", relief="raised", command=lambda : self.append_button(1))
        self.button1.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.button2 = Button(self.frame4, text="2", bg="white", bd=20, fg="black", relief="raised", command=lambda : self.append_button(2))
        self.button2.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.button3 = Button(self.frame4, text = "3", bg="white", bd=20, fg="black", relief="raised", command=lambda : self.append_button(3))
        self.button3.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.SubtractButton = Button(self.frame4, text = "-", bg="white", bd=20, fg="black", relief="raised", command = self.subtract).pack(side=LEFT)
        self.button0 = Button(self.frame5, text = "0", bg="white", bd=20).pack(side=LEFT)
        self.Clear = Button(self.frame5, text = "C", bg="white", fg="black", bd=20, command = self.clear).pack(side=LEFT)
        self.AddButton = Button(self.frame5, text = "+", bg="white", bd=20, command = self.add).pack(side=LEFT)
        self.EqualsButton = Button(self.frame5, text ="=", bg="white", bd=20, command = self.equals_button)
        self.EqualsButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.button = ""
        self.total = 0
        self.firstNumber = []
        self.operand = ""
        self.root.mainloop
        self.count = 0
        self.multiplyValue = 0

    def clear(self):
        self.evar.set("")
        self.firstNumber = []
        return self.firstNumber

    def callback(self, *args):
        print("Entry now %s" % self.evar.get())

    def add(self):
        self.firstNumber.append(int(self.evar.get()))
        self.evar.set("")
        self.operand = "+"

    def subtract(self):
        self.firstNumber.append(int(self.evar.get()))
        self.evar.set("")
        self.operand = "-"

    def multiply(self):
        self.firstNumber.append(int(self.evar.get()))
        self.evar.set("")
        self.operand = "*"

    def divide(self):
        self.firstNumber.append(int(self.evar.get()))
        self.evar.set("")
        self.operand = "/"

    def create_button(self):
        buttons = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

    def append_button(self, val):
        self.evar.set(self.evar.get() + str(val))

    #when equals is presssed, perform a calculation based on the operand
    def equals_button(self):
        if self.operand == "+":
            self.firstNumber.append(int(self.evar.get()))
            result = sum(self.firstNumber)
        elif self.operand == "-":
            result = sum(self.firstNumber) - int(self.evar.get()) 
        elif self.operand == "*":
            self.multiplyValue = 1
            for x in self.firstNumber:
                self.multiplyValue *= x
            result = self.multiplyValue * int(self.evar.get()) 
        elif self.operand == "/":
            result = sum(self.firstNumber) / int(self.evar.get()) 
        self.evar.set(result)


Calc = Calculator()
```

Comment: Can't you append the data to a variable and then use `eval`?

Comment: Calculating infix expressions can be a bit tricky. I would suggest checking out the [postfix algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation#Postfix_algorithm). Where `6 * 6 - 1` would turn into `6 6 * 1 -` and still evaluate to 35.

Comment: Ah, the postfix algorithm was EXACTLY what my coworker was talking about last night but he didn't mention it by name. Good to know. I was also unfamiliar with eval, both those might help me figure this out.